# Using AND criteria on text field in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create/design a query in MS Access. I'm sorry I don't know the correct terminology of what I am trying to do. I am trying to update some inventory and my data looks like this.

```
Music Table
item no.  Record Status
01           DELETE
02           DELETE
03           DELETE
04           DELETE
07           DELETE
01           ADD        
04           ADD
06           ADD
```

In my data items that have both DELETE and ADD are updates. I am trying to write a query to create a table filters these particular items. Any suggestions? I tried using the Query Design View.
Field -> Record Status,Table-> Music Table and put 'DELETE' And 'ADD' in the Criteria but it just showed me a blank table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use DELETE **Or** ADD, not DELETE **And** ADD

Comment: @Rene if I use DELETE Or  ADD wouldn't it select all of the rows?

Comment: Correct. If that's not what you're after, then please clarify. Some more sample data plus an output example might help. Your issue description is not quite clear.

Comment: In the example above item no. 01 has a record status of both DELETE and ADD I want the entries that are both. Some records are just DELETES and others are ADDs. I want the records that are inclusively ADDS and DELETES. IDK maybe I should split the data up and then do an inner join based on the item number.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed have to use an inner join on item number.
This should work:

```
SELECT a.[item no.], a.[Record Status]
FROM Music a
WHERE a.[Record Status] IN ('ADD','DELETE')
AND EXISTS
(
SELECT '1'
FROM Music b
WHERE a.[item no.] = b.[item no.]
AND b.[Record Status] IN ('ADD','DELETE')
AND b.[Record Status] <> a.[Record Status]
)
ORDER BY a.item, a.status
```

Comment: Why do you use EXISTS? Do you have to do that everytime you use a subquery?